# Bedeutung von "noch lange nicht"

Tags: meaning, phrase, idiom

Ich bin ein bisschen verwirrt bezüglich der Bedeutung dieser zwei Sätze:

1. > Wir sind noch lange nicht fertig mit der Arbeit.

Ich denke das bedeutet: wir sind erst seit Kurzem fertig mit der Arbeit. Richtig?

2. > Das heißt noch lange nicht, dass....(Nebensatz)

Was bedeutet dieser Satz?

3. Was bedeutet "längst nicht" in einem Satz?

Comment: Vielen Dank für die  Bearbeitung

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Häufig kann man die Reihenfolge der Satzbestandteile variieren, aber hier ist die Reihenfolge wichtig.

> Wir sind noch nicht fertig mit der Arbeit.

Die Arbeit ist noch nicht erledigt.

> Wir sind noch **lange nicht** fertig mit der Arbeit.

Die Arbeit ist noch nicht erledigt, und das wird noch lange dauern, bis die Arbeit erledigt ist.

> Wir sind noch **nicht lange** fertig mit der Arbeit.

Dies bedeutet tatsächlich, wir sind erst seit Kurzem fertig mit der Arbeit. Die Reihenfolge ist hier aber gegenüber dem ursprünglichen Satz vertauscht.

Als Annäherung kann man "noch lange nicht" ersetzen durch "nicht" oder "noch nicht", wobei das "lange nicht" die Bedeutung noch verstärkt. Beim ersten Beispiel ist es ein direkter zeitlicher Bezug. Wenn die Arbeit "noch nicht" fertig ist, könnte sie in den nächsten Sekunden fertig werden. Bei "noch lange nicht" wird es länger dauern.

Bei "das heißt/bedeutet noch lange nicht" hat das lange keine zeitliche Bedeutung, sondern sagt, dass eine Schlussfolgerung nicht nur falsch, sondern "sehr" falsch ist.

"Noch längst nicht" könnte als Steigerung von "noch lange nicht" verwendet werden.

Answer (score 6):

> "Wir sind noch nicht fertig" = "We're not done yet"

> "Wir sind noch lange nicht fertig" = "We're not done yet by a long shot"

The figurative meaning is similar:

> "Das heißt noch nicht, dass X" = "That doesn't necessarily mean X"

> "Das heißt noch lange nicht, dass X" = "That definitely doesn't mean X yet"

In all these cases the superlative "längst" means largely the same as the positive "lange".

Comment: Es gibt hier - soweit ich weiß - die Konvention Fragen in der Sprache zu beantworten, in der die Frage gestellt wurde.. :)

Comment: Denjenigen (wie mir), die Deutsch und Englisch genauso schlecht verstehen, hilft die Übersetzung nicht unbedingt ;)  Nun habe ich eher *by a long shot* gelernt, aber die Antwort könnte der/dem  OP gewidmet werden.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Hilfe

Answer (score 0):

> Wir sind noch lange nicht fertig mit der Arbeit.

ist ein Widerspruch. Es widerspricht der Vorstellung, die Arbeit wäre bald erledigt.

> Das heißt noch lange nicht, dass… (Nebensatz)

ist auch ein Widerspruch. Es verneint die Vorstellung, dass aus dem vorher Besprochenen die im Nebensatz umschriebene Schlussfolgerung auch nur annäherend gezogen werden könnte. "Noch lange nicht" könnte man dabei ersetzen durch "längst nicht".

(Yes, I prefer answering in English any time.)

Comment: @amadeusamadeus  Its nice to feel saved. If I could vote for an edit, I would.